# How to create an installation file server

Tags: java, installation

I have a server java project, which runs on glassfish.

How does it put into the package and run on any machine and install it?

Comment: Ever heard of a question mark? Is yes, use it! You have combined at least three questions into one post. What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making Multiplateform installer with Izpack is really easy and fun. You can package your application in installer and run on any machine. Just go through the tutorial [here](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=89) and you will have your own installer.

Answer (score 3):

Glassfish is a heavy server. If you wants to deploy your application on several machines, you should use a lighter Java server.

You can look at theses project, which provide a package with an embedded Jetty web server (with startup scripts for all plarforms: Windows, Linux, Mac, Solaris, etc.).

- http://jenkins-ci.org/
- http://www.sonarsource.org/
- http://nexus.sonatype.org/

Once your application can work on an embedded Jetty server, create an installer will be much easier (with InnoSetup, IzPack, etc.).

Comment: Absolutely, Glassfish is completely oversized!